# Java bytecode execution not understood how go statement works in bytecode

Tags: java, bytecode

```
class Condition{

     public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i =10;

        if(i==10){

            System.out.println("low");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("high");
        }

    }
}
```

above given  a sample programme:

below bytecode:

```
0: bipush        10
2: istore_1
3: iload_1
4: bipush        10
6: if_icmpne     20
9: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
12: ldc           #3                  // String low
14: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
17: goto          28
20: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
23: ldc           #5                  // String high
25: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
28: return
```

i not understood whole working of bytecode how it executes 
how go instruction work

Comment: Instruction at offset 17: goto 28? The next instruction executed following that is a offset 28: return. The instruction immediately follow the goto at offset 20 is executed if the instruction at offset 6 takes the branch.

Answer (score 1):

`if_icmpne 20` means: Compare *(`cmp`)* the 2 `int` values *(`i`)* on the operand stack, and if *(`if`)* they are not equal *(`ne`)* go to byte code at offset 20 *(`20`)*. See [***if_icmp***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.if_icmp_cond).

`goto 28` means: Go to *(`goto`)* byte code at offset 28 *(`28`)*. See [***goto***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.goto).

To see description of all the byte code instructions, see chapter 6 of [The Java® Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/).